# How to get each element in one corner with Flexbox CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put one link to each corner (left, top, right, bottom) using Flexbox

I tried `top: 0` or setting `flex-direction` to `column`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <a href="one/">ONE</a>
    <a href="two/">TWO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="three/">THREE</a>
    <a href="four/">FOUR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect to get one link to each corner like this screenshot:

[image]

but I got this instead

[image]

Comment: just add `height: 100vh` in your `body` tag in CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and simple flexbox solution (no hacks or absolute positioning):

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between; /* horizontal spacing */
  align-content: space-between;   /* vertical spacing */
}

.top, .bottom {
  flex-basis: 100%;    /* to force .bottom to wrap */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  background-color: orange;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <a href="one/">ONE</a>
    <a href="two/">TWO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="three/">THREE</a>
    <a href="four/">FOUR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, `position: absolute;` might be better.

```
.container { position: relative; }

.top-left { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 }

.top-right { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0 }

.bottom-left { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0 }

.bottom-right { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because of the height on your `bottom` and `top` divs it will only occupy min-content height as default also the same for the wrapper container

---

this is one way how you can fix it using only flexbox :

```css
.container {
   height: 95vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction : column;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.top {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.bottom {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="one/">ONE</a>
        <a href="two/">TWO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="three/">THREE</a>
        <a href="four/">FOUR</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.top & .bottom` for flexbox. Flexbox can handle with less HTML code.

```
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.container a {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.container a:nth-child(2n) {
    text-align: right;
}

.container a:nth-child(3),
.container a:nth-child(4) {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">ONE</a>
    <a href="#">TWO</a>
    <a href="#">THREE</a>
    <a href="#">FOUR</a>
</div>
```